# Cardinal direction enum from range input

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom

Still learning JS and I made the following function to convert degrees into cardinal directions respectively. My first iteration of the code was over 50 lines and I was able to get it down to 13 using a for loop.

Is there a way to optimize or simplify the code down even more? Is my logic and implementation ideal?

https://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/JjPGNmY

```js
function setCardinalDirection() {
  value = document.querySelector('#orientation').value // Get current value from range input
  document.querySelector(".degrees").textContent = value // Inject current input value into label
  direction = document.querySelector(".direction") // Define intercardinal direction display element

  degrees = 22.5 // Define range between two intercardinal directions
  cardinal = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW", "N"]

  for ( i = cardinal.length; i >= 0; i-- ) { // Iterate through cardinal array backwards
    if ( value < degrees/2 + degrees * i ) {
      cardinalOut = cardinal[i]
    }
  }

  direction.textContent = cardinalOut // Inject current cardinal value into label
}

document.querySelector("#orientation").addEventListener('input', function(event) {
 setCardinalDirection()
})

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 setCardinalDirection()
})
```

```html
<form>
  <label for ="orientation">
    Orientation: <strong><span class="degrees"></span>° (<span class="direction"></span>)</strong>
  </label>
  <br />
  <input id="orientation" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="1" value="145">
</form>
```

Comment: @konijn I did not see this, caching issue perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Evaluation

For somebody learning Javascript this code isn't bad, however it does have some inefficiencies and practices that are frowned upon (e.g. Global variables). See the suggestions below for advice about improving it.

### Suggestions

#### Semicolon terminators

Unless you are intimately familiar with [the statements that need to be terminated by a semicolon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) it is wise to always terminate each line with a semi-colon.

#### Selecting elements by class vs id attribute

The first line selects an element from the DOM by the *id* attribute - i.e. `document.querySelector('#orientation')`. The next line uses a *class* selector to select an element: `document.querySelector(".degrees")`. If there is only one element with class name `degrees` that matters for this application then an *id* attribute would be more appropriate than *class*.

Also, it isn't wrong to use `document.querySelector()` to get elements by *id* but using [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) "*is definitely faster*" <sup>[1](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/280663/2)</sup> (see [this jsPerf test for comparison](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector)). Similarly `document.getElementsByClassName()` is also faster. I would suggest only using `document.querySelector()` when there is a complex selector (e.g. `form lable[for="direction']`

#### Global variables

Any variable not declared with a keyword like `var`, `const` or `let` is considered `global`. For a small application like this it likely wouldn't lead to any issues but in a larger application it could lead to unintentional side-effects if the same name is used in different functions.

#### Excess closures

The lines to add event listeners can be simplified:

> ```
> document.querySelector("#orientation").addEventListener('input', function(event) {
>   setCardinalDirection()
> })
>
> window.addEventListener("load", function(){
>  setCardinalDirection()
> })
> ```

Instead of wrapping the calls to `setCardinalDirection()` in an extra function, just pass the name of the function:

```
document.querySelector("#orientation").addEventListener('input', setCardinalDirection); 
window.addEventListener("load", setCardinalDirection);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

I have taken your input and updated my CodePen: https://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/JjPGNmY

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the for loop with `cardinalOut = cardinal[Math.floor((value / degrees) + 0.5)]`.